# Why won't useAsyncData work on SSR in Nuxt3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, nuxt3

I move from Nuxt2 to Nuxt3 and I have struggle with SSR API call.
I want to execute API call on SSR, but API is called on client side and is visible in network.

On Nuxt2 there is no problem when using:

```
async asyncData(...
```

Here is my code on Nuxt3:

```
<script setup >
const { data: apiData, pending } = await useAsyncData('api-test', async () => {
  return await $fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products")
});
</script>
```

I get data, but API call is visible in network, which is not ok.
I try 'every' example available, I try to set SSR: true in defineNuxtConfig .. Nothing helps.
What am I missing?

Comment: This method will always be called on the client side when navigating between routes. This is not a method that should be used to hide the api call from the client.

Comment: No? How come? In docs it is said that this is SSR - so request should happen on SSR.
So, what is the new way to get data in Nuxt3? In Nuxt2 it was:
  async asyncData({route, $axios}) 
and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

OK - I create new app and try to do SSR and now it seems that it works good and API call is hidden.
In my layout I had this:

```
 this.$nextTick(() => {
   this.pageLoading = false;
 });
```

I remove it and SSR started to work.